# Примеры графики на C++

Tags: консоль, c++

Как рисовать графические объекты в C++ в консоли, допустим, круг, квадрат и другие. Я работаю в DEV C++.

Comment: Моя вопрос не понимай. Что значит "примеры графических объектов"?

Comment: Короче, как сделать квадрат и круг на C++

Comment: Где сделать? В bmp-файле, в окошке, в консоли, на ЧПУ с 250 Вт лазером? Буквами али точками?..

Comment: В консоле =)

Comment: ncurses -> google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм... Консоль. Т.к. рисовать настоящую графику в консоли не представляется возможным, то рисование надо делать символами.

Все символы в консоли одинаковой ширины. Значит, можно их рассматривать как точки.

Как вывести, например, квадрат 7х7? Самый простой и дубовый способ:

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++) printf("XXXXXXX\n");
```

Если надо его сдвинуть - просто выведем перед ним пустые строки и символы пробела сколько нам надо. И квадрат будет не в углу торчать...

Естественно, для всех стандартных геометрических объектов существуют алгоритмы растеризации (превращения в набор точек). Например, для линии хорошо известен алгоритм Брезенхема. Для круга тоже оный имеется. Или ещё какие.

Почитайте книги по программированию, где в названии есть термины "Компьютерная графика", "Машинная графика", "Алгоритмы машинной графики" и что-то в этом духе. Там всё очень популярно должно объясняться, как именно рисовать объекты, с картинками и алгоритмами.

Вот. Это если подходить "с нуля".

А так, конечно, есть готовые библиотеки для подобных рисований.

Comment: А если дез иксов!? Чистый квадрат.

Comment: Смотрите таблицу символов =) Там, вроде, были полностью закрашенные символы(прямоугольнички). Хотя с треугольником такой фокус уже не пройдёт.

Comment: А как же дез фона, квадрат с ни чем в нутри

Comment: Только контур? Есть и такие символы в таблице. Если вы посмотрите все, то увидите. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Псевдографика

Хотя там, конечно, надо смотреть какой угол какой и ставить соответствующий символ.

Answer (score 0):

Для реальных задач - ncurses или pdcurses. Для учебных задач - самостоятельное [рисование](http://www.denvo.ru/pub/programming/console-decor.html) псевдографикой.

Answer (score 0):

вообще если из консоли то можете попробовать подключить OpenGL библиотеки (погуглите glut, opengl). Достаточно интересно, как-то давно мне нравилось писать небольшие графические приложения

Answer (score 0):

я конечно может не понял вопрос, но в Borland C++ при подключении <graphics.h> можно переводить консоль в графический режим и рисовать в ней. для круга есть оператор circle(x,y,R); прямоугольник и другие фигуры можно нарисовать при помощи line(x1,y1,x2,y2); графики функций поточечно putpixel(x,y,color);. Может в DEV C++ этого нет?